# how to search filter with pagination best practice reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, search

I have a problem if on page 1 and after (except 2) what I search (type) if there is data it will display the data that I search (type), see the picture below:

[image]

the problem is if on page 2, what I search for will appear on another page. even though on page 2 the data is there, :
[image]

This is page 2 before searching :
[image]

and this is page 1 before searching
[image]

if I'm on page 2 there is data that appears abc and dcs. if I search for dcs then dcs appear or if I type d it will appear d and if on other pages there is also data it will display

I use this codesanbox.io url: 
[https: //codesandbox.io/embed/condescending-pine-d7q3v](https://codesandbox.io/s/condescending-pine-d7q3v)

and this my code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import dummyQnA from "./dummyQnA.json";
import "./styles.css";
import { Row, Col, Pagination, Button, Table, Divider } from "antd";
import Search from "antd/lib/input/Search";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";

const columns = [
  {
    title: "Question",
    dataIndex: "questionAndAnswer",
    key: "questionAndAnswer"
  }
];

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      search: ""
    };
  }

  getHighlightedText(text, higlight) {
    if (!higlight.trim()) {
      return <span>{text}</span>;
    }
    let parts = text.split(new RegExp(`(${higlight})`, "gi"));
    return (
      <span>
        {parts
          .filter(part => part)
          .map((part, i) => (
            <mark
              key={i}
              style={
                part.toLowerCase() === higlight.toLowerCase()
                  ? { backgroundColor: "yellow" }
                  : {}
              }
            >
              {part}
            </mark>
          ))}
      </span>
    );
  }

  renderQnA = (qna, i) => {
    return {
      key: i,
      questionAndAnswer: [
        <Col key={i} md={24} style={{ marginTop: 20 }}>
          <Row>
            <Col md={23}>
              <b>
                {" "}
                {this.getHighlightedText(qna.questionAdmin, this.state.search)}
              </b>
              <p style={{ color: "#417505" }}>
                {" "}
                {this.getHighlightedText(qna.answerCustomer, this.state.search)}
              </p>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Col>
      ]
    };
  };

  onChange = e => {
    this.setState({ search: e.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { search } = this.state;
    const lowercasedFilter = search.toLowerCase();
    const filteredQnA = dummyQnA.filter(item => {
      return Object.keys(item).some(key =>
        item[key].toLowerCase().includes(lowercasedFilter)
      );
    });
    return (
      <div className="product-forum">
        <Row className="title-inline">
          <Col md={13} style={{ paddingTop: "6px" }}>
            <span className="title-inline__title">
              Pertanyaan terkait Produk ({dummyQnA.length})
            </span>
          </Col>
          <Col md={3}>
            <Button
              type="link"
              className="title-inline__button-live-chat"
              onClick={this.handleLiveChat}
            >
              LIVE CHAT
            </Button>
          </Col>
          <Col md={8}>
            <Search
              value={this.state.search}
              placeholder="Cari pertanyaan terkait"
              onChange={this.onChange}
            />
          </Col>
        </Row>
        <Table
          className="table-qna"
          showHeader={false}
          pagination={{ defaultPageSize: 5 }}
          dataSource={filteredQnA.map((QnA, i) => this.renderQnA(QnA, i))}
          columns={columns}
        />
        <Divider />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: What is the question here? What are you trying to do? and what have you tried to do? There's no context so its hard to know your specific situation. Please post a question with more detail and include an example of what you have tried that isn't working

Comment: Please remember that you're asking people who have no idea what you're doing, to help you. As such, make sure that you're following the advice listed in the [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask) policy article, and update your post accordingly. There is nowhere near enough information in your post right now for people to help you.

Comment: sorry I just press submit, and I've completed the questions above

Comment: Instead of posting pictures, post code please. Describe the behavior that you arent seeing and then the code that is effectively trying to achieve that.

Comment: Generally pagination is reflected in the URL itself. This way refreshing the page will reload the correct data. You need to render a result set from a search and paginate on that. If you do a second search then clear out the pagination because its a new search.

Comment: how to make search better, can explain with an example of the code